# xCode - how to link dynamic framework from workspace

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-workspace

What is the proper way to link a dynamic framework which lives in the same workspace like the app?

I have a problem when adding the framework from the products folder to the App's "Embedded Binaries" section - because the added framework may be built for simulator and the app builds against iphoneos. I can not add both, can I?

I want to achieve that when my app builds, the framework is built too and I can work the changes immediately instead of doing some cumbersome update via Carthage or something link that.

EDIT: http://netsplit.com/xcode-two-apps-with-a-shared-private-framework-in-a-workspace This blog post describes exactly what i want to do - but this does not work since i want to develop on simulator and iphone (it would require a fat framework). Or did I miss something.

Answer (score 1):

Although is possible to develop main app and framework and doing integration test in the same time from many workspaces, at same point becomes a slow-ish and not scalable development process.

So I suggest you to make a sample app in the workspace of your framework and develop and test your features directly from there. Once your framework is quite stable you release it and you integrate it with your main app.

Comment: What do you mean with "integrate it with your main app". Someone has to copy it manually to a place where the main app can use it.

Comment: Manually it's of course possible, better if you integrate it with Carthage (my favourite one, link here: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage), CocoaPods (https://cocoapods.org) or PackageManager (https://swift.org/package-manager/).